# Kivy Black Screens With a TextInput

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using Kivy `1.11.1` on Python `3.7`, Ubuntu `20.04`.

When I run my program my code shows a window, but the window is completely black and does not respond to any input.

My code is like this:

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.3961, 0.4627, 0.8, 1)


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def btn1Click(self, instance):
        print('The button was clicked')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.button1 = Button(text='Click Me', font_size=14)
        self.button1.bind(on_press=self.btn1Click)
        self.add_widget(self.button1)
        self.add_widget(TextInput())


class CreateMachineProgram(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CreateMachineProgram().run()
```

When I comment out the line `self.add_widget(TextInput())`, all of a sudden my code loads properly. What am I doing wrong?